# Jenkins Groovy Script MissingPropertyException

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

To create the following form of json file
I made a Groovy script as below, but an error occurred.

What's wrong?

I'm on the next site.
I think I wrote the Groovy sample code correctly.
https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html

sample json

```
{
    "loglevel": "INFO",
    "logformat":"%(asctime)s, %(funcName)s, [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    "logdateformat":"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    "webconsole": "192.168.152.154",
    "userid": "dGVzdA==",
    "userpw": "dGVzdA==",
    "headless": "true",
    "autoexit": "true",
    "os": {
        "scan": "True",
        "policy": null,
        "host": null,
        "ip": null,
        "domain": null,
        "os": "all"
    }
}
```

groovy script

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import groovy.json.*

// read build parameters
env = build.getEnvironment(listener)

loglevel = env.get('loglevel')
logformat= env.get('logformat')
logdateformat= env.get('logdateformat')
webconsole= env.get('webconsole')
userid= env.get('userid')
userpw= env.get('userpw')
headless= env.get('headless')
autoexit= env.get('autoexit')

scan= env.get('scan')
policy= env.get('policy')
host= env.get('host')
ip= env.get('ip')
domain=env.get('domain')
os= env.get('os')
Instance= env.get('Instance')

// prepare json
def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder {
    loglevel  loglevel 
    logformat logformat
    logdateformat logdateformat
    webconsole webconsole
    userid userid
    userpw userpw
    headless headless
    autoexit autoexit

    dbms(
        scan: scan,
        policy: policy,
        host: host,
        ip: ip,
        domain: domain,
        os: os,
        instance: instance,
    )
}

json = builder.toPrettyString()

// print to console and write to a file
println json
new File("C:\\workspace\\jenkins\\_Test\\TestScript\\config.json").write(json)
```

jenkins error status

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
```

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: instance for class: groovy.json.JsonDelegate
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:36)
at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
at groovy.json.JsonDelegate.cloneDelegateAndGetContent(JsonDelegate.java:86)
at groovy.json.JsonBuilder.call(JsonBuilder.java:215)
at groovy.json.JsonBuilder$call$1.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:26)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:377)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:314)
at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.run(SystemGroovy.java:95)
at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:59)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:197)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Execute system Groovy script' marked build as failure

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it's
The instance variable name should be lowercase, but it is in uppercase as follows.

Instance= env.get('Instance')